# PGFPlots cone weird artefact at the cusp

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I am using the following code to plot a cone in 3D:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, zlabel={$z$},
    domain=0:1,
    y domain=0:2*pi,
    xmin=-1.5, xmax=1.5,
    ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5, zmin=-1.5, zmax=0.1,
    colormap/blackwhite,
    samples=20,
    samples y=20,
    z buffer=sort,
    unit vector ratio=1 1 1
]
    \addplot3[surf] ({x*cos(deg(y))},{x*sin(deg(y))},{-x});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, I end up with a few weird line extensions near the top. How do I get rid of them?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `miter limit=1` and the spikes will be gone.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-1.5, xmax=1.5,
        ymin=-1.5, ymax=1.5,
        zmin=-1.5, zmax=0.1,
        xlabel={$x$},
        ylabel={$y$},
        zlabel={$z$},
        domain=0:1,
        y domain=0:2*pi,
        samples=20,
        samples y=20,
        z buffer=sort,
        unit vector ratio=1 1 1,
        colormap/blackwhite,
        miter limit=1,          % <-- added
    ]
        \addplot3[surf] ({x*cos(deg(y))},{x*sin(deg(y))},{-x});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Great that my answer helps you. You could -- besides upvoting my answer (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it) -- accept it (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Comment: Could you elaborate on the use of miter limit? I have accepted your answer now.